# Devo utilizar crase para falar de um período de tempo?

Tags: ortografia, crase

Estava lendo um pouco [as perguntas sobre o uso de crases](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crase) e fiquei com algumas dúvidas quando utilizamos para se tratar de um período de tempo.

Por exemplo, a frase abaixo deveria possuir crase?

> O horário de atendimento é de 09:00 as 18:00.

E em um outro sentido, como por exemplo esse abaixo:

> Eu retornarei as 15:00.

E após algumas outras preposições, como **para, até, desde, entre, etc**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementando a resposta de Artefacto, quando estiver em dúvida se há artigo e preposição em determinado "a", **substitua o "a" por uma outra preposição antes do substantivo (para, até, em, etc) e veja se há necessidade do artigo "a"**.  Por exemplo:

- Eu decidi ir **a** Nova York. Eu decidi ir **até** Nova York. Eu estou **em** Nova York. (o "a" é só uma preposição, não há crase)
- Eu decidi ir **à** Torre dos Cléricos.  Eu decidi ir **até a** Torre dos Cléricos. Eu estou **na** (em + a) na Torre dos Cléricos. (Nesse segundo exemplo, existe o artigo "a" e a preposição "a" em "ir à Torre..." e portanto há a ocorrência de crase)

Em outras situações, **substitua o substantivo por uma palavra masculina.  Se "a"/"as" mudar para "ao/aos", é porque existia crase**. Por exemplo:

- Seus cabelos estão cheirando **a** gasolina - Seus cabelos estão cheirando **a** álcool. (não há crase)
- Eu vou **à** praia aos domingos - Eu vou **ao** cinema aos domingos. (presença de crase)

Finalmente, respondendo a sua pergunta "E após algumas outras preposições, como para, até, desde, entre, etc?", **crase só é possível com a preposição "a"**, pois corresponde a junção da preposição "a" com o artigo "a/as" ou com os pronomes demonstrativos "aquele(s) /aquela(s) /aquilo.

ps **Observe que crase não é o acento**. Crase é a junção da preposição "a" com o artigo ou pronome demonstrativo.  **Havendo a ocorrência de crase, deve se usar o acento grave.** O acento, portanto, é apenas indicativo da ocorrência de crase.

Answer (score 2):

> O horário de atendimento é das 9 [horas] às 18 [horas].
>   Retornarei às 15 [horas].

Neste caso, para uma hora definida (não incluindo aqui *durou três horas*, por exemplo), usa-se o artigo definido e portanto há crase quando a preposição é *a*. A palavra *horas* está elidida. O artigo usa-se independentemente da preposição.

> Vemo-nos às 6 / a partir das 6 / até às 6 / pelas 6 / entre as 6 e as 10.

Há quem prefira *até as 6*, por entender que *até* não deve ser seguido da preposição *a*, mas nesse caso é a preposição que falta, não o artigo.

Não se usa o artigo, contudo, ao dizer as horas: *são 6 horas*.